# Spring boot, validate JSON before deserialization

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, validation, deserialization

I'm trying to validate JSON POST data before deserialization with kotlin and spring boot.

I have this controller:

```java
package fr.rtransat.tvtracker.api.controllers.actor

import fr.rtransat.tvtracker.api.requests.CreateActorRequest
import fr.rtransat.tvtracker.domain.actor.command.CreateActor
import fr.rtransat.tvtracker.domain.actor.command.CreateActorCommand
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class CreateActorController(
    private val command: CreateActor
): AbstractActorController() {
    @PostMapping
    fun invoke(@RequestBody body: CreateActorRequest) {
        command.handle(CreateActorCommand(body.name, body.isActive))
    }
}
```

```java
package fr.rtransat.tvtracker.api.requests

import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class CreateActorRequest(
    val name: String,
    @SerialName("is_active")
    val isActive: Boolean
)
```

I use kotlinx.serialization but when I have a missing field in my json I have this error: `Could not read kotlinx.serialization.json.Json$Default@45bb062f: Field 'name' is required for type with serial name 'fr.rtransat.tvtracker.api.requests.CreateActorRequest', but it was missing at path: $`,

I'm wondering how to avoid this exception and handle the error with a json response containing custom error. Even if all fields are set I want to validate name with a not empty string validator
But I don't think I can validate the data before deserialization right? So I need to validate the json before ? (with an openapi schema for example maybe?)
I want json response instead of any exception, because for me a validation error is not a bug so I don't need to have exceptions.